# select specific area of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I made a carousel using 2 divs named "left" and "right" putting mousemove events on them. I wanted to make it go up and down as well so I created a "top" and "bottom" and noticed that I couldn't make them combine to go the way the cursor goes.

I thus thought of targeting a specific area in the container (i.e top half of my container div) instead of creating divs inside triggering a specific direction, this way (I think) I can trigger all these event altogether. However after now hours of research I couldn't find a way to do so.

How should I proceed ? here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/pool4/vL5g3/3/

```
var x=0, 
    y=0,
    rateX=0,
    rateY=0,
    maxspeed=10;
var backdrop = $('.backdrop');

$('.directionx', backdrop).mousemove(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var left = $this.is('.left');
    var right = $this.is('.right');

    if (left){
        var w = $this.width();
        rateX = (w - e.pageX - $this.offset().left + 1)/w;
    }
    else if (right){
        var w = $this.width();
        rateX = -(e.pageX - $this.offset().left + 1)/w;
    }
});
$('.directiony', backdrop).mousemove(function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var top = $this.is('.top');
    var bottom = $this.is('.bottom');  

    if (top){
        var h = $this.height();
        rateY = (h - e.pageY - $this.offset().top + 1)/h;
    }
    else if (bottom) {
        var h = $this.height();
        rateY = -(e.pageY - $this.offset().top + 1)/h;
    }
});


backdrop.hover(
    function(){
        var scroller = setInterval( moveBackdrop, 30 );
        $(this).data('scroller', scroller);
    },
    function(){
        var scroller = $(this).data('scroller');
        clearInterval( scroller );
    }
);   

function moveBackdrop(){
    x += maxspeed * rateX;
    y += maxspeed * rateY;
    var newpos = x+'px '+y+'px';
    backdrop.css('background-position',newpos);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the divs that control movement up and down are placed over the ones that control left and right, so the latter do not receive the mousemove event ever. Mouse events do not propagate through layers, even if they're transparent. I changed your code and CSS, so each div is in one of the corners. To make things easier, I've used data-* attributes so the direction controlled by each div is set in a declarative way, without the need to change the code. You'll see that the code is much simpler (and it could be simplified even more).

By the way, you could achieve this witout extra divs, just controlling where the cursor is (to the top, right, left or bottom of the center of the div).

```
backdrop.on('mousemove', '.dir', function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var direction = $(e.target).attr('data-direction');
    var left = direction.indexOf('left') > - 1;
    var right = direction.indexOf('right') > - 1;
    var top = direction.indexOf('up') > - 1;
    var bottom = direction.indexOf('down') > - 1;

    if (left){
        var w = $this.width();
        rateX = (w - e.pageX - $this.offset().left + 1)/w;
    }
    else if (right){
        var w = $this.width();
        rateX = -(e.pageX - $this.offset().left + 1)/w;
    }

    if (top){
        var h = $this.height();
        rateY = (h - e.pageY - $this.offset().top + 1)/h;
    }
    else if (bottom) {
        var h = $this.height();
        rateY = -(e.pageY - $this.offset().top + 1)/h;
    }
});
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL5g3/4/).

**EDIT** In this new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL5g3/11/) I do it without extra divs:

```
var w = backdrop.width() / 2;
var h = backdrop.height() / 2;
var center = {
    x: backdrop.offset().left + backdrop.width() / 2,
    y: backdrop.offset().top + backdrop.height() / 2
};

backdrop.on('mousemove', function(e){   
    var offsetX = e.pageX - center.x;
    var offsetY = e.pageY - center.y;

    rateX = -offsetX / w;
    rateY = -offsetY / h;
});

backdrop.hover(
    function(){
        var scroller = $(this).data('scroller');
        if (!scroller) {
            scroller = setInterval( moveBackdrop, 30 );
            $(this).data('scroller', scroller);
        }
    },
    function(){
        var scroller = $(this).data('scroller');
        if (scroller) {
            clearInterval( scroller );
            $(this).data('scroller', null);
        }
    }
);
```

As you see, the mousmove handler is considerably simpler.

Comment: Thanks awfully,  it's really clear. Could you by the way tell me more about the way to achieve it without extra div ? I have been looking for it as well but couldn't find the right method to do so.

Comment: Wow ye, nicely done. I'm going to learn a lot from it. However there's one thing I dont understand, it seems like the axes are inverted but I can't seem to find an error in the maths, is it normal ?

Comment: Actually there was. Efectively, the axis were inverted, I didn't realise. Now they work perfectly, and even with less code. http://jsfiddle.net/vL5g3/11/

Comment: Perfect, in addition I get to improve in maths, thanks awfully for your time !

Answer (score 1):

To avoid issue of children losing event could use just the one.

First HTML from 4 child divs to just one

```
<div class="backdrop">
    <div class="direction"></div>
</div>
<div id="pos"></div>
```

Next Inside the mousemove find your relative position

```
//Get Relative Position
    var relX = e.pageX - $this.offset().left;
    var relY = e.pageY - $this.offset().top;
```

Get Relative Position as a percentage of width and put 50% of it in negative for direction

```
var w = $this.width();
rateX = ((relX / w) - 0.5) * -1;

var h = $this.height();
rateY = ((relY / h) - 0.5) * -1;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vL5g3/12/)

Comment: That sounds like a great solution to the issue, however in your fiddle the directions are opposed. I tried to figure out where in the maths it went wrong however none of my changes seems to fix it.

Comment: @BrennanSei oops was too entranced by the stars, updated